# Make jquery code shorter

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide, mouseleave

I know my code could be shorter as what I've now. But I just don't know how to shorten it. I would like to do this because it's making everything clearer. Also this code makes everything slower then it needs to be.

html

```
   <div id="slider">
    <div id="slideLeft">
        <div class="slideText">
            <h1>Ik zoek werk</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                Suspendisse iaculis magna sed lacus vestibulum venenatis. 
                Quisque sem turpis, semper vitae gravida sit amet, tristique ut ligula. 
            </p>
            <div class="slideButton">Bekijken</div>
        </div>
        <img src="../_/img/slidetest.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="slideRight">
        <div class="slideText">
            <h1>Ik zoek personeel</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
                Suspendisse iaculis magna sed lacus vestibulum venenatis.
                Quisque sem turpis, semper vitae gravida sit amet, tristique ut ligula. 
            </p>
            <div class="slideButton">Bekijken</div>         
        </div>
        <img class="slideImgSolid" src="../_/img/slidetest3.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#slider{width:100%;min-height:450px;background-color:#999;}
#slideLeft{width:50%;position:absolute;left:0;background-color:#333;height:450px;overflow:hidden;}
#slideRight{width:50%;position:absolute;right:0;height:450px;background-color:#666;overflow:hidden;}

.slideText{position:absolute;top:50%;overflow:hidden;width:400px;z-index:100;}
#slideLeft .slideText{right:0;}
#slideRight .slideText{left:-150px;}

#slider h1{position:relative;font-size:18px;background-color:white;padding:5px 15px 5px 15px;}
#slideRight .slideText h1{text-align:right;left:0px;}
#slideLeft .slideText h1{text-align:left;right:-150px;}
#slider p{position:relative;width:300px;right:-400px;margin:20px 0 0 0;}
.slideButton{position:relative;right:0;right:-400px;margin:10px 0 0 0;background-color:#888;width:70px;padding:5px;text-align:center;}
.slideImgSolid{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;}
```

js

```
$('#slideLeft').mouseenter(function(){
    $("#slideRight").animate({
       width: '30.1%',
       easing: 'easInOutCubic'                 
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $("#slideLeft p").animate({
       right: '0px',
       easing: 'easInOutCubic'
    }, { duration: 100, queue: false });
    $("#slideLeft h1").animate({
       right: '0px',
       easing: 'easInOutCubic'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $("#slideLeft .slideButton").animate({
       right: '0px',
       easing: 'easInOutCubic'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $("#slideLeft").animate({
       width: '70%',
       easing: 'easInOutCubic',
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    });

$('#slideLeft').mouseleave(function(){
    $("#slideRight").animate({
       width: '50%',
       easing: 'easInOutCubic'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $("#slideLeft h1").animate({
       right: '-150px',
       easing: 'easInOutCubic'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $("#slideLeft p").animate({
       right: '-400px',
       easing: 'easInOutCubic'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $("#slideLeft .slideButton").animate({
       right: '-400px',
       easing: 'easInOutCubic'
    }, { duration: 100, queue: false });
    $("#slideLeft").animate({
       width: '50%',
       easing: 'easInOutCubic'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false });
});
```

Comment: Do you know you can put commas in selectors ?

Comment: no I didn't. That will help a bit

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily agree that this code could be much shorter. As dystroy suggested, you could put `#slideLeft h1` and `#slideLeft .slideButton` into one function call, but other than that, your animated objects need different individual values, so I don't see what you can do to make the code smaller or faster. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @Grüse You're right that this wouldn't make the code much shorter. This was just a comment, not an answer. I propose an answer below.

Comment: @dystroy I know, I was just referencing your helpful comment. I wasn't trying to attack what you said, sorry if it sounded that way. +1 for your answer, I like it.

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest solution I see would be to define objects :

```
var objects = [
  {selector: "#slideLeft p", enterright: '0px', leaveright: '-400px', duration: 200},
   ...
];
```

And then use

```
   $('#slideLeft').mouseenter(function(){
       $.each(objects, function(){
           $(this.selector).animate({
               right: this.enterright,
               easing: 'easInOutCubic'
           }, { duration: this.duration, queue: false });
       });
   }).mouseleave(function(){
       $.each(objects, function(){
           $(this.selector).animate({
               right: this.leaveright,
               easing: 'easInOutCubic'
           }, { duration: this.duration, queue: false });
       });
   });
```

This would be easy to extend and manage as all important parameters are in the `objects` array declaration.

If you're sure your objects don't change, you might want to replace the selector in the objects declaration with the resulting jQuery object for a slightly more efficient code :

```
var objects = [
  {$obj: $("#slideLeft p"), enterright: '0px', leaveright: '-400px', duration: 200},
  ...
```